# unexpected T_ELSEIF

Tags: php, foreach

```
$pages = array("grac", "zamknij", "dolaczyc");
$pagesid = array("showNews", "showThread", "showProfile");

foreach ($pagesid as $page) {
  if (isset($_GET[$page])) {
  include('sobra/'.$page.'.php');
  }
}

// just pages
elseif (in_array($_GET['page'], $pages)) {
include("$_GET[page].php");
}

// error
else include('error.php');
```

gives:
*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSEIF in C:\WAMP\www\sdgag\index.php on line 33*

This should work i think.. what the problem can be?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps another approach. Do your logic, and determine what page you want to include ultimately. After all of the logic has been done, include your determined page.

*The following is untested, and may contain errors. Let me know, and I'll update the code.*

```
<?php

  // Predefined list of acceptable pages
  $pages = array("one","two","three");
  $pagesid = array("four","five","six");

  // Gather any user-defined page request
  $desPage = trim($_GET["page"]);

  // Assume they are wrong, and need to see error.php
  $pageToLoad = "error.php";

  // If the user request is not empty
  if (!empty($desPage)) {
    if (in_array($desPage,$pages)) {
      $pageToLoad = $desPage . ".php";
    }
  } else {
  // User request is empty, check other variables
    foreach ($pagesid as $pageid) {
      if (isset($_GET[$pageid])) {
        $pageToLoad = $pageid . ".php";
      }
    }
  }

  // Show output page
  include($pageToLoad);

?>
```

Answer (score 8):

The elseif and the else aren't attached to the if, you've put them outside of the foreach loop block.

Answer (score 3):

**There is one closing bracket to much before the else.**

It should read:

```
$pages = array("grac", "zamknij", "dolaczyc");
$pagesid = array("showNews", "showThread", "showProfile");

foreach ($pagesid as $page) {
  if (isset($_GET[$page])) {
    include('sobra/'.$page.'.php');
  }
  // just pages
  else if (in_array($_GET['page'], $pages)) {
    include("$_GET[page].php");
  }
  // error
  else include('error.php');
}
```

**If you indent your source code correctly such errors show up fast and you can fix them yourself.**

Comment: Your "else" is not connected to the conditional statements. It's trailing your foreach().

Comment: that last else is still out of the if clause

Comment: Oah, sh** your right, fixed it

Comment: that outputs everything in error.php 3 times :/

Comment: Because that's what your code is currently written to do. If that's not what you're expecting, you should probably re-think your approach.

Answer (score -2):

```
$pages = array('grac', 'zamknij', 'dolaczyc');
$pagesid = array('showNews', 'showThread', 'showProfile');

foreach ($pagesid as $page) {
  if (isset($_GET[$page])) {
    include('sobra/'.$page.'.php');
  }
  // just pages
  else if (in_array($_GET['page'], $pages)) {
    include($_GET[$page].'.php'); // fixed missing $, restylized to match previous style
  }
  else include('error.php');
}
```