# PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them

Tags: php, parsing, debugging, syntax-error

Everyone runs into syntax errors. Even experienced programmers make typos. For newcomers, it's just part of the learning process. However, it's often easy to interpret error messages such as:

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in index.php on line 20

The unexpected symbol isn't always the real culprit. But the line number gives a rough idea of where to start looking.

> Always look at the **code context**. The syntax mistake often hides in the mentioned *or* in **previous code lines**. Compare your code against syntax examples from the manual.

While not every case matches the other. Yet there are some [general steps to **solve syntax mistakes**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18050072).
This references summarized the common pitfalls:

- [Unexpected T_STRING](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18092277)
- [Unexpected T_VARIABLE 
   Unexpected '$varname' (T_VARIABLE)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18092267)
- [Unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING 
   Unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18092288)
- [Unexpected $end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them#29500670)
- [Unexpected T_FUNCTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723748/php-version-5-2-14-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-function-expecting)…
- [Unexpected `{`
  Unexpected `}`
  Unexpected `(`
  Unexpected `)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18092308)
- [Unexpected `[`
  Unexpected `]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29505827)
- [Unexpected T_IF 
   Unexpected T_FOREACH 
   Unexpected T_FOR 
   Unexpected T_WHILE 
   Unexpected T_DO 
   Unexpected T_PRINT 
   Unexpected T_ECHO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18092318)
- [Unexpected T_LNUMBER](//stackoverflow.com/a/47202089)
- [Unexpected ?](//stackoverflow.com/a/48670368)
- [Unexpected continue (T_CONTINUE)
  Unexpected continue (T_BREAK)
  Unexpected continue (T_RETURN)](//stackoverflow.com/a/51786865)
- [Unexpected '='](//stackoverflow.com/a/53037930)
- [Unexpected T_INLINE_HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934754/t-inline-html-whats-wrong-with-this)…
- [Unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966010/what-does-this-mean-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-paamayim-nekudotay)…
- [Unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990212/help-with-this-error-message-unexpected-t-object-operator)…
- [Unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622624/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-double-arrow-php)…
- [Unexpected T_SL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208725/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-sl-php-heredoc)…
- [Unexpected T_BOOLEAN_OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419095/syntax-error-unexpected-t-boolean-or)…

  [Unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500935/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-boolean-and-expecting-in)…
- [Unexpected T_IS_EQUAL 

  Unexpected T_IS_GREATER_OR_EQUAL 

  Unexpected T_IS_IDENTICAL 

  Unexpected T_IS_NOT_EQUAL 

  Unexpected T_IS_NOT_IDENTICAL 

  Unexpected T_IS_SMALLER_OR_EQUAL 

  Unexpected `<` 

  Unexpected `>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30142092/345031)
- [Unexpected T_NS_SEPARATOR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263105/parsing-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-ns-separator)…
- [Unexpected character in input: '`\`' (ASCII=92) state=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156251/unexpected-character-in-input-ascii-92-state-1)
- [Unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) 
   Unexpected 'private' (T_PRIVATE) 
   Unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED) 
   Unexpected 'final' (T_FINAL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341378/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-public)…
- [Unexpected T_STATIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668557/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-static)…
- [Unexpected T_CLASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205590/laravel-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-class-expecting-t-string-or-t-v)…
- [Unexpected 'use' (T_USE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342994/unexpected-use-t-use-when-trying-to-use-composer)
- [Unexpected T_DNUMBER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27783613/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-dnumber-in-home-a3206525-public-html-ea)
- [Unexpected `,`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241208/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-in) *(comma)*
- [Unpexected `.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969342/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-expecting-or) *(period)*
- [Unexpected `;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961248/php-string-parse-error-with-necessary-semicolon-after-variable) *(semicolon)*
- [Unexpected `*`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32905365/3933332) *(asterisk)*
- [Unexpected `:`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178974/parse-error-unexpected-works-fine-in-localhost) *(colon)*
- [Unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ')'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65539862)
- [Unexpected `&`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665782/php-warning-call-time-pass-by) (call-time pass-by-reference)
- [Unexpected `.`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61407635/250259)

Closely related references:

- [What does this error mean in PHP? (runtime errors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

  - [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_XXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12770089/#12770089)
  - [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/13935532#13935532)
  - [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/15539535#15539535)
- [What does this symbol mean in PHP? (language tokens)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)
- [Those `“”` smart  `‘’` quotes mean nothing to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303353/double-quotes-are-not-copied-normally-how-can-i-edit-them)

And:

- The [PHP manual on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/) and its various [language tokens](http://php.net/tokens)
- Or Wikipedia's [syntax introduction on PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_syntax_and_semantics).
- And lastly our [**php** tag-wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) of course.

While Stack Overflow is also welcoming rookie coders, it's mostly targetted at professional programming questions.

- Answering everyone's coding mistakes and narrow typos is considered mostly off-topic.
- So please take the time to follow the [basic steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18050072), before posting syntax fixing requests.
- If you still have to, please show your own solving initiative, attempted fixes, and your thought process on what looks or might be wrong.

If your *browser* displays error messages such as "SyntaxError: illegal character", then it's not actually [php](/questions/tagged/php)-related, but a [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)-[syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120093/how-to-find-javascript-syntax-errors).

---

**Syntax errors raised on vendor code:** Finally, consider that if the syntax error was not raised by editing your codebase, but after an external vendor package install or upgrade, it could be due to PHP version incompatibility, so check the vendor's requirements against your platform setup.

Comment: This isn't enough data to be an answer, but one could write a analyser with parsekit_compile_string, and put more friendly answers on it.  If integrated into your IDE, this could be quite informative.

Comment: You put an impressive amount of work into this. Respect for that. It's probably very good for teachers to learn to fast point out errors or for those creating IDEs or implementing quick fixes. However, IDEs will already effectively do most of this work for you, as @Panique suggests. Additionally, im many cases the start again from scratch is a good option.

Comment: Should we add PHP 7 errors preventive?

Comment: @Rizier123 Sure, if you have one, or just a link even. I've not yet seen questions myself. (If it's interesting enough, I'll throw in a bounty.. :)

Comment: mario, I *strongly* recommend that you take your error-specific answers here and extract them out into their own Q&A pairs (or contribute them to existing questions, when they exist), then delete those answers from here, update the index to link to the distinct questions, and flag this question for locking. The *content* you've created here is awesome, but its usefulness is crippled by a lack of findability on Google; I discovered this answer today for the first time ever after being active on Stack Overflow for years.

Comment: When I Google for the error names listed in the question here, I *don't find this post* on even the first page of Google, ever. That's a huge waste of what is otherwise fantastic work! Googling "unexpected T_STRING" gets me [this piece of garbage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685584/unexpected-t-string-error-in-php) which has 50% as many views as your *entire error reference* here. This could be solved easily by extracting out Q&A pairs with good titles. See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314618/error-reference-collections-bane-or-boon

Comment: @MarkAmery Wholeheartedly agree. But this reference is a test balloon still. It's bordering on off-topic because it covers multiple topics at once and doesn't aid googleability by itself. Which, of course, it should. Outsouring it into higher ranking results (and hoping it stays there) is the long-term plan. For the moment it's just used as memorable reference for newcomer-friendly dupe closing - because finding a fitting *exact* T_STRING answer was near impossible already.

Comment: @mario I'm not sure what's stopping you from migrating most of the content out to self-answered Q&A pairs right now? For the answers where you cover multiple error types in one post, I can see how that would require some thought and care, but that's only a couple of posts. I'd move all the rest out right now myself except that it's your content (and I don't have the ability to delete the posts here once I'm done). As far as off-topicness goes, there's a few reference indexes like this and I'd fiercely defend the right of this one to exist... as long as the content is migrated out.

Comment: @mario Would `unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)` fall under this Q&A? I've noticed a few questions lately but wasn't 100% sure if I could use this question to close them with. One posted today being http://stackoverflow.com/q/37499362/

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think most causes are similar to the `T_IF / T_FOREACH / ...` block. Albeit I wanted to compile a more custom summary for IF/ELSE/ELSEIF questions.

Comment: @Rizier123 Edit away! - It's all pretty much still the initial draft; wasn't meant to remain like this. (Still reads too much like a book/tutorial intro). The overall answer format is perhaps okay.

Comment: @mario Well I thought you have some ideas how you would like it or think it would be better or so? Like you said that you wanted to outsource this stuff. Otherwise I would make a gist draft and then you can say it if it is better or worse? :)

Comment: @Rizier123 Nah, just give it whirl here. I'm not really attached to any formulation quirk or structure ;} Also, it's CW after all (should have been from the start). And, mods are asleep, so edit away!

Comment: You know, I wish I had had this list when I was learning PHP years ago.Very helpful, especially for beginners.

Comment: That question could use a `T_USE` parse error answer. I'd add the answer for it later

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Great idea; there've been quite a handful of these questions recently. Though it would need to cover the three common cases (import scope, traits, closures) if possible.

Comment: Some of the linked pages are missing e.g unexpected t_double_arrow

Answer (score 325, accepted):

#### What are the syntax errors?

PHP belongs to the [C-style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_C-based_programming_languages) and [imperative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) programming languages. It has rigid grammar rules, which it cannot recover from when encountering misplaced symbols or identifiers. It can't guess your coding intentions.

[image: Function definition syntax abstract]

#### Most important tips

There are a few basic precautions you can always take:

- Use proper **code indentation**, or adopt any lofty coding style.
  Readability prevents irregularities.
- Use an [***IDE*** or editor for PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_editors) with **syntax highlighting**.
  Which also help with parentheses/bracket balancing.

  [image: Expected: semicolon]
- Read [the language reference](http://www.php.net/langref) and examples in the manual.
  Twice, to become somewhat proficient.

#### How to interpret parser errors

A typical syntax error message reads:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected **T_STRING**, expecting **'`;`'** in *file.php* on **line** *217*

Which lists the *possible* location of a syntax mistake. See the mentioned **file name** and **line number**.

A [moniker](http://php.net/tokens) such as `T_STRING` explains which symbol the parser/tokenizer couldn't process finally. This isn't necessarily the cause of the syntax mistake, however.

It's important to look into **previous code lines** as well. Often syntax errors are just mishaps that happened earlier. The error line number is just where the parser conclusively gave up to process it all.

### Solving syntax errors

There are many approaches to narrow down and fix syntax hiccups.

- Open the mentioned source file. Look at the mentioned **code line**.

  - For runaway strings and misplaced operators, this is usually where you find the culprit.
  - Read the line left to right and imagine what each symbol does.
- More regularly you need to look at **preceding lines** as well.

  - In particular, missing `;` semicolons are missing at the previous line ends/statement. (At least from the stylistic viewpoint. )
  - If `{` code blocks `}` are incorrectly closed or nested, you may need to investigate even further up the source code. Use proper *code indentation* to simplify that.
- Look at the **syntax colorization**!

  - Strings and variables and constants should all have different colors.
  - Operators `+-*/.` should be tinted distinct as well. Else they might be in the wrong context.
  - If you see string colorization extend too far or too short, then you have found an unescaped or missing closing `"` or `'` string marker.
  - Having two same-colored punctuation characters next to each other can also mean trouble. Usually, operators are lone if it's not `++`, `--`, or parentheses following an operator. Two strings/identifiers directly following each other are incorrect in most contexts.
- **Whitespace is your friend**.
   Follow *any* coding style.
- Break up long lines temporarily.

  - You can freely **add newlines** between operators or constants and strings. The parser will then concretize the line number for parsing errors. Instead of looking at the very lengthy code, you can isolate the missing or misplaced syntax symbol.
  - Split up complex `if` statements into distinct or nested `if` conditions.
  - Instead of lengthy math formulas or logic chains, use temporary variables to simplify the code. (More readable = fewer errors.)
  - Add newlines between:

    1. The code you can easily identify as correct,
    2. The parts you're unsure about,
    3. And the lines which the parser complains about.

    Partitioning up long code blocks *really* helps to locate the origin of syntax errors.
- **Comment out** offending code.

  - If you can't isolate the problem source, start to comment out (and thus temporarily remove) blocks of code.
  - As soon as you got rid of the parsing error, you have found the problem source. Look more closely there.
  - Sometimes you want to temporarily remove complete function/method blocks. (In case of unmatched curly braces and wrongly indented code.)
  - When you can't resolve the syntax issue, try to **rewrite** the commented out sections **from scratch**.
- As a newcomer, avoid some of the confusing syntax constructs.

  - The ternary `? :` condition operator can compact code and is useful indeed. But it doesn't aid readability in all cases. Prefer plain `if` statements while unversed.
  - PHP's alternative syntax (`if:`/`elseif:`/`endif;`) is common for templates, but arguably less easy to follow than normal `{` code `}` blocks.
- The most prevalent newcomer mistakes are:

  - Missing semicolons `;` for terminating statements/lines.
  - Mismatched string quotes for `"` or `'` and unescaped quotes within.
  - Forgotten operators, in particular for the string `.` concatenation.
  - Unbalanced `(` parentheses `)`. Count them in the reported line. Are there an equal number of them?
- Don't forget that solving one syntax problem can uncover the next.

  - If you make one issue go away, but other crops up in some code below, you're mostly on the right path.
  - If after editing a new syntax error crops up in the same line, then your attempted change was possibly a failure. (Not always though.)
- Restore a backup of previously working code, if you can't fix it.

  - Adopt a source code versioning system. You can always view a `diff` of the broken and last working version. Which might be enlightening as to what the syntax problem is.
- **Invisible stray Unicode characters**: In some cases, you need to [use a hexeditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28952930/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-variable/28953112#28953112) or different editor/viewer on your source. Some problems cannot be found just from looking at your code.

  - Try [`grep --color -P -n "\[\x80-\xFF\]" file.php`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001177/how-do-i-grep-for-all-non-ascii-characters-in-unix) as the first measure to find non-ASCII symbols.
  - In particular BOMs, zero-width spaces, or non-breaking spaces, and smart quotes regularly can find their way into the source code.
- Take care of which **type of linebreaks** are saved in files.

  - PHP just honors <kbd>\n</kbd> newlines, not <kbd>\r</kbd> carriage returns.
  - Which is occasionally an issue for MacOS users (even on OS  X for misconfigured editors).
  - It often only surfaces as an issue when single-line `//` or `#` comments are used. Multiline `/*...*/` comments do seldom disturb the parser when linebreaks get ignored.
- If your **syntax error does not transmit over the web**:
   It happens that you have a syntax error on your machine. But posting the very same file online does not exhibit it anymore. Which can only mean one of two things:

  - You are looking at the wrong file!
  - Or your code contained invisible stray Unicode (see above).
    You can easily find out: Just copy your code back from the web form into your text editor.
- Check your **PHP version**. Not all syntax constructs are available on every server.

  - `php -v` for the command line interpreter
  - `<?php phpinfo();` for the one invoked through the webserver.

  Those aren't necessarily the same. In particular when working with frameworks, you will them to match up.
- Don't use [PHP's reserved keywords](http://www.php.net/reserved.keywords) as identifiers for functions/methods, classes or constants.
- Trial-and-error is your last resort.

If all else fails, you can always **google** your error message. Syntax symbols aren't as easy to search for (Stack Overflow itself is indexed by [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/) though). Therefore it may take looking through a few more pages before you find something relevant.

Further guides:

- *[PHP Debugging Basics](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2004/08/12/debuggingphp.html)* by David Sklar
- *[Fixing PHP Errors](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/05/fixing-php-errors/)* by Jason McCreary
- *[PHP Errors – 10 Common Mistakes](http://www.phpreferencebook.com/misc/php-errors-common-mistakes/)* by Mario Lurig
- *[Common PHP Errors and Solutions](http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/common-php-errors-solution_t)*
- *[How to Troubleshoot and Fix your WordPress Website](http://diythemes.com/thesis/troubleshoot-wordpress-website/)*
- *[A Guide To PHP Error Messages For Designers](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/30/a-guide-to-php-error-messages-for-designers/)* - Smashing Magazine

#### White screen of death

If your website is just blank, then typically a syntax error is the cause.
Enable their display with:

- `error_reporting = E_ALL`
- `display_errors = 1`

In your [`php.ini`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) generally, or via [`.htaccess`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) for mod_php,
or even [`.user.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) with FastCGI setups.

Enabling it within the broken script is too late because PHP can't even interpret/run the first line. A quick workaround is crafting a wrapper script, say `test.php`:

```
<?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set("display_errors", 1);
   include("./broken-script.php");
```

Then invoke the failing code by accessing this wrapper script.

It also helps to enable PHP's `error_log` and look into your [webserver's `error.log`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-logs/) when a script crashes with HTTP 500 responses.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` for earlier versions of PHP

Comment: Some IDEs (like NetBeans) not only support syntax highlighting but also code formatting. If you get into the habit of formatting your code properly and asking the IDE to reformat just in case from time to time you may catch hard to spot problems like unmatched braces.

Answer (score 120):

I think this topic is totally overdiscussed/overcomplicated. Using an IDE is THE way to go to completely avoid any syntax errors. I would even say that working without an IDE is kind of unprofessional. Why? Because modern IDEs check your syntax after every character you type. When you code and your entire line turns red, and a big warning notice shows you the exact type and the exact position of the syntax error, then there's absolutely no need to search for another solution.

### Using a syntax-checking IDE means:

**You'll (effectively) never run into syntax errors again, simply because you see them right as you type. Seriously.**

*Excellent IDEs with syntax check (all of them are available for Linux, Windows and Mac):*

1. [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) [free]
2. [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) [$199 USD]
3. [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) with [PHP Plugin](https://eclipse.org/pdt/) [free]
4. [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/) [$80 USD] (mainly a text editor, but expandable with plugins, like [PHP Syntax Parser](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter))

Comment: It is obviously. However, relisting IDEs here, can you elaborate a bit where they differ in their syntax helpfulness? Sublime is mostly an editor, not IDE; but then more pretty and snappy; does primarily just syntax highlighing but's also veritable at bracket matching. It easily discovers T_CONSTANT_AND_ENCAPSED errors instantly for example, unlike PHPStorm; which however does more squiggly lines for inline errors. NetBeans´ syntax hints used to be more cryptic than PHPs even (relisting allowed constructs rather). Can you share your experience on pros/cons; is your favorite Eclipse/PDT or..?

Comment: @mario I think you are really deep into the topic so i really dont want to say anything wrong here, but all the code I (and my team mates, friends who code, freelance partners) have ever written in an IDE never ever was executed with a syntax error. So I think at least Netbeans/PHPStorm's syntax check is extremely powerful. But maybe I've misread your question. Gimme some hours ... ;)

Comment: Your answer is already spot on. Would fit 99% of our questions. However for the context here I'd like a trade-off consideration on *which IDE provides the more newbie-friendly tooltips*. It's probably minor to us, colorization and squiggly lines being sufficient if you're versed enough. But I presume the differences could be more significant to beginners.

Comment: Sometimes an IDE is not a feasible option. For example, making quick edits to a WordPress theme or plugin. Yes, I could copy all the code into an IDE, but then I have to open it up, paste it all in there, set headers and all that other time wasting crap, when I'm just hoping for a quick edit. Now, if you're developing new features or starting from scratch, then, yes, do it in an IDE. You won't regret taking that bit of extra time at the start to set it up.

Comment: @user1934286 You should consider not editing plugins or themes on the server you're running it on. Changes should be tested locally, and IDEs like PhpStorm will happily work with a WordPress tree. You can then push the changes to the server. If it's a bigger site, there should also be considerations around doing proper deployments.

Comment: @SimaoGomesViana For *my* sites, I do have a local instance and I edit in Sublime. But when a friend calls, or I'm screwing around with a new site that's not really live yet, I do edit straight on server. If I'm worried about it, I backup the file locally, but I've also backed it up on the server to. Lol. I'm just saying, sometimes there's nothing wrong with quick and dirty.

Comment: That said, Sublime conveniently can copy a server's entire directory tree, and usually it's pretty good at reading the headers already there and linking files for you, so the part about pasting in my 6 year old comment is not really a thing anymore. But still, I wouldn't download a whole directory if I figured I'd only be editing this one time.

Answer (score 61):

### Unexpected `[`

These days, the unexpected `[` array bracket is commonly seen on outdated PHP versions. The [short array syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) is available since PHP **>= 5.4**. Older installations only support `array()`.

```
$php53 = array(1, 2, 3);
$php54 = [1, 2, 3];
         ⇑
```

Array function result dereferencing is likewise not available for older PHP versions:

```
$result = get_whatever()["key"];
                      ⇑
```

[Reference - What does this error mean in PHP? - "Syntax error, unexpected `\[`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/22316776#22316776) shows the most common and practical workarounds.

Though, you're always better off just upgrading your PHP installation. For shared webhosting plans, first research if e.g. `SetHandler php56-fcgi` can be used to enable a newer runtime.

See also:

- [PHP syntax for dereferencing function result → possible as of PHP 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1779256)
- *[PHP syntax error, unexpected '['](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206928/php-syntax-error-unexpected)*
- *[Shorthand for arrays: is there a literal syntax like {} or []?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271874/shorthand-for-arrays-is-there-a-literal-syntax-like-or)*
- *[PHP 5.3.10 vs PHP 5.5.3 syntax error unexpected '['](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23565971/php-5-3-10-vs-php-5-5-3-syntax-error-unexpected)*
- *[PHP Difference between array() and []](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772534/php-array-square-brackets-and-array-difference)*
- *[PHP Array Syntax Parse Error Left Square Bracket "["](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912233/php-array-syntax-parse-error-left-square-bracket)*

BTW, there are also preprocessors and [PHP 5.4 syntax down-converters](https://github.com/IonutBajescu/short-arrays-to-long-arrays) if you're really clingy with older + slower PHP versions.

**Other causes for *Unexpected `[`* syntax errors**

If it's not the PHP version mismatch, then it's oftentimes a plain typo or newcomer syntax mistake:

- You can't use [array property declarations/expressions in classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887187/php-5-6-3-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-in-class), not even in PHP 7.

  ```
  protected $var["x"] = "Nope";
                ⇑
  ```
- Confusing `[` with opening curly braces `{` or parentheses `(` is a common oversight.

  ```
  foreach [$a as $b)
          ⇑
  ```

  Or even:

  ```
  function foobar[$a, $b, $c] {
                 ⇑
  ```
- Or trying to dereference constants (before PHP 5.6) as arrays:

  ```
  $var = const[123];
         ⇑
  ```

  At least PHP interprets that `const` as a constant name.

  If you meant to access an array variable (which is the typical cause here), then add the leading `$` sigil - so it becomes a `$varname`.
- You are trying to use the `global` keyword on a member of an associative array.  This is not valid syntax:

  ```
  global $var['key'];
  ```

#### Unexpected `]` *closing* square bracket

This is somewhat rarer, but there are also syntax accidents with the terminating array `]` bracket.

- Again mismatches with `)` parentheses or `}` curly braces are common:

  ```
  function foobar($a, $b, $c] {
                            ⇑
  ```
- Or trying to end an array where there isn't one:

  ```
  $var = 2];
  ```

  Which often occurs in *multi-line* and *nested* array declarations.

  ```
  $array = [1,[2,3],4,[5,6[7,[8],[9,10]],11],12]],15];
                                               ⇑
  ```

  If so, use your IDE for bracket matching to find any premature `]` array closure. At the very least use more spacing and newlines to narrow it down.

Comment: The link 'PHP 5.4 syntax down-converters' https://github.com/IonutBajescu/short-arrays-to-long-arrays above is broken.

Comment: "function foobar[$a, $b, $c] {" I thought functions were declared like "function foobar($a, $b, $c){" ????

Answer (score 51):

### Unexpected T_VARIABLE

An "unexpected `T_VARIABLE`" means that there's a literal `$variable` name, which doesn't fit into the current expression/statement structure.

[image: purposefully abstract/inexact operator+$variable diagram]

1. #### Missing semicolon

   It most commonly indicates [a missing semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135784/syntax-error-unexpected-t-variable) in the previous line. Variable assignments following a statement are a good indicator where to look:

   ```
           ⇓
    func1()
    $var = 1 + 2;     # parse error in line +2
   ```
2. #### String concatenation

   A frequent mishap are [string concatenations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606145/php-syntax-error-unexpected-t-variable-expecting-or-on-line-29) with forgotten `.` operator:

   ```
                                   ⇓
    print "Here comes the value: "  $value;
   ```

   Btw, you should prefer [string interpolation](http://php.net/types.string#language.types.string.parsing) (basic variables in double quotes) whenever that helps readability. Which avoids these syntax issues.

   > String interpolation is a *scripting language* core feature. No shame in utilizing it. Ignore any micro-optimization advise about variable `.` concatenation being *faster*. **It's not.**
3. #### Missing expression operators

   Of course the same issue can arise in other expressions, for instance arithmetic operations:

   ```
               ⇓
    print 4 + 7 $var;
   ```

   PHP can't *guess* here if the variable should have been added, subtracted or compared etc.
4. #### Lists

   Same for syntax lists, like in array populations, where the parser also indicates an expected comma `,` for example:

   ```
                                          ⇓
    $var = array("1" => $val, $val2, $val3 $val4);
   ```

   Or functions parameter lists:

   ```
                                    ⇓
    function myfunc($param1, $param2 $param3, $param4)
   ```

   Equivalently do you see this with `list` or `global` statements, or when lacking a `;` semicolon in a `for` loop.
5. #### Class declarations

   This parser error also occurs [in class declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122729/im-getting-a-syntax-error-unexpected-t-variable-error-i-dont-see-what-im). You can only assign static constants, not expressions. Thus the parser complains about variables as assigned data:

   ```
    class xyz {      ⇓
        var $value = $_GET["input"];
   ```

   Unmatched `}` closing curly braces can in particular lead here. If a method is terminated too early (use proper indentation!), then a stray variable is commonly misplaced into the class declaration body.
6. #### Variables after identifiers

   You can also never have [a variable follow an identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194156/php-syntax-error-unexpected-t-variable) directly:

   ```
                 ⇓
    $this->myFunc$VAR();
   ```

   Btw, this is a common example where the intention was to use [variable variables](http://php.net/variables.variable) perhaps. In this case a variable property lookup with `$this->{"myFunc$VAR"}();` for example.

   > Take in mind that using variable variables should be the exception. Newcomers often try to use them too casually, even when arrays would be simpler and more appropriate.
7. #### Missing parentheses after language constructs

   Hasty typing may lead to forgotten opening or closing parenthesis
   for `if` and `for` and `foreach` statements:

   ```
           ⇓
    foreach $array as $key) {
   ```

   Solution: add the missing opening `(` between statement and variable.

   ```
                          ⇓
    if ($var = pdo_query($sql) {
         $result = …
   ```

   The curly `{` brace does not open the code block, without closing the `if` expression with the `)` closing parenthesis first.
8. #### Else does not expect conditions

   ```
        ⇓
   else ($var >= 0)
   ```

   Solution: Remove the conditions from `else` or use [`elseif`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php).
9. #### Need brackets for closure

   ```
        ⇓
   function() use $var {}
   ```

   Solution: Add brackets around `$var`.
10. #### Invisible whitespace

    As mentioned in the [reference answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18050072/345031) on "Invisible stray Unicode" (such as a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)), you might also see this error for unsuspecting code like:

    ```
    <?php
                              ⇐
    $var = new PDO(...);
    ```

    It's rather prevalent in the start of files and for copy-and-pasted code. Check with a hexeditor, if your code does not visually appear to contain a syntax issue.

#### See also

- [Search: unexpected T_VARIABLE](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+php%20parse%20error%20unexpected#q=site:stackoverflow.com+php+parse+error+unexpected+T_VARIABLE)

Answer (score 33):

### Unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING 
 Unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE

The unwieldy names `T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING` and `T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE` refer to quoted ***`"string"`** literals*.

They're used in different contexts, but the syntax issue are quite similar. *T_ENCAPSED…* warnings occur in double quoted string context, while *T_CONSTANT…* strings are often astray in plain PHP expressions or statements.

1. #### Incorrect variable interpolation

   And it comes up most frequently for incorrect PHP variable interpolation:

   ```
                             ⇓     ⇓
   echo "Here comes a $wrong['array'] access";
   ```

   Quoting arrays keys is a must in PHP context. But in double quoted strings (or HEREDOCs) this is a mistake. The parser complains about the contained single quoted `'string'`, because it usually expects a literal identifier / key there.

   More precisely it's valid to use PHP2-style [simple syntax within double quotes](http://www.php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.parsing) for array references:

   ```
   echo "This is only $valid[here] ...";
   ```

   Nested arrays or deeper object references however require the [complex curly string expression](http://www.php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.parsing#complex+curly+syntax) syntax:

   ```
   echo "Use {$array['as_usual']} with curly syntax.";
   ```

   If unsure, this is commonly safer to use. It's often even considered more readable. And better IDEs actually use distinct syntax colorization for that.
2. #### Missing concatenation

   If a string follows an expression, but lacks a concatenation or other operator, then you'll see PHP complain about the string literal:

   ```
                          ⇓
   print "Hello " . WORLD  " !";
   ```

   While it's obvious to you and me, PHP just can't *guess* that the string was meant to be appended there.
3. #### Confusing string quote enclosures

   The same syntax error occurs when [confounding string delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565768/php-syntax-error-unexpected-t-constant-encapsed-string). A string started by a single `'` or double `"` quote also ends with the same.

   ```
                   ⇓
   print "<a href="' . $link . '">click here</a>";
         ⌞⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⌟⌞⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⌟⌞⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⌟
   ```

   That example started with double quotes. But double quotes were also destined for the HTML attributes. The intended concatenation operator within however became interpreted as part of a second string in single quotes.

   > **Tip**: Set your editor/IDE to use slightly distinct colorization for single and double quoted strings. (It also helps with application logic to prefer e.g. double quoted strings for textual output, and single quoted strings only for constant-like values.)

   This is a good example where you shouldn't break out of double quotes in the first place. Instead just use [proper `\"` escapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674121/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-constant-encapsed-string-expecting) for the HTML attributes´ quotes:

   ```
   print "<a href=\"{$link}\">click here</a>";
   ```

   While this can also lead to syntax confusion, all better IDEs/editors again help by colorizing the escaped quotes differently.
4. #### Missing opening quote

   Equivalently are [forgotten opening `"`/`'` quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379114/how-to-fix-unexpected-t-constant-encapsed-string-syntax-error) a recipe for parser errors:

   ```
                  ⇓
    make_url(login', 'open');
   ```

   Here the `', '` would become a string literal after a bareword, when obviously `login` was meant to be a string parameter.
5. #### Array lists

   If you miss a `,` comma in an array creation block, the parser will see two consecutive strings:

   ```
   array(               ⇓
        "key" => "value"
        "next" => "....",
   );
   ```

   Note that the last line may always contain an extra comma, but overlooking one in between is unforgivable. Which is hard to discover without syntax highlighting.
6. #### Function parameter lists

   The same thing [for function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352932/syntax-error-unexpected-t-constant-encapsed-string):

   ```
                            ⇓
   myfunc(123, "text", "and"  "more")
   ```
7. #### Runaway strings

   A common variation are quite simply forgotten string terminators:

   ```
                                   ⇓
   mysql_evil("SELECT * FROM stuffs);
   print "'ok'";
         ⇑
   ```

   Here PHP complains about two string literals directly following each other. But the real cause is the unclosed previous string of course.
8. #### HEREDOC indentation

   Prior [PHP 7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305869/heredoc-interfering-with-code-indentation), the [heredoc string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) end delimiter can't be prefixed with spaces:

   ```
   print <<< HTML
       <link..>
       HTML;
      ⇑
   ```

   Solution: upgrade PHP or find a better hoster.

**See also**

- [Interpolation (double quoted string) of Associative Arrays in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738850/interpolation-double-quoted-string-of-associative-arrays-in-php)
- [PHP - syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565768/php-syntax-error-unexpected-t-constant-encapsed-string)
- [Syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719350/syntax-error-unexpected-t-constant-encapsed-string-in-php)
- [Unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING error in SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333823/unexpected-t-constant-encapsed-string-error-in-sql-query)

Answer (score 30):

### Unexpected T_STRING

`T_STRING` is a bit of a misnomer. It does not refer to a quoted `"string"`. It means a raw identifier was encountered. This can range from `bare` words to leftover `CONSTANT` or function names, forgotten unquoted strings, or any plain text.

1. #### Misquoted strings

   This syntax error is most common for misquoted string values however. Any unescaped and stray `"` or `'` quote will form an invalid expression:

   ```
                  ⇓                  ⇓
    echo "<a href="http://example.com">click here</a>";
   ```

   Syntax highlighting will make such mistakes super obvious. It's important to remember to use backslashes for escaping `\"` double quotes, or `\'` single quotes - depending on which was used as [string enclosure](http://php.net/language.types.string).

   - For convenience you should prefer outer single quotes when outputting plain HTML with double quotes within.
   - Use double quoted strings if you want to interpolate variables, but then watch out for escaping literal `"` double quotes.
   - For lengthier output, prefer multiple `echo`/`print` lines instead of escaping in and out. Better yet consider a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc) section.

   Another example is using PHP entry inside HTML code generated with PHP:

   ```
   $text = '<div>some text with <?php echo 'some php entry' ?></div>'
   ```

   This happens if `$text` is large with many lines and developer does not see the whole PHP variable value and focus on the piece of code forgetting about its source. Example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59598335/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-sonum-t-string-in)

   See also *[What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)*.
2. #### Unclosed strings

   If you [miss a closing `"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968629/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-string) then a syntax error typically materializes later. An unterminated string will often consume a bit of code until the next intended string value:

   ```
                                                          ⇓
   echo "Some text", $a_variable, "and some runaway string ;
   success("finished");
            ⇯
   ```

   It's not just literal `T_STRING`s which the parser may protest then. Another frequent variation is an [`Unexpected '>'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507796/troubleshooting-parse-error-unexpected-error) for unquoted literal HTML.
3. #### Non-programming string quotes

   If you *copy and paste* code from a blog or website, you sometimes end up with invalid code. [Typographic quotes aren't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762558/php-t-string-error) what PHP expects:

   ```
   $text = ’Something something..’ + ”these ain't quotes”;
   ```

   Typographic/smart quotes are Unicode symbols. PHP treats them as part of adjoining alphanumeric text. For example `”these` is interpreted as a constant identifier. But any following text literal is then seen as a bareword/T_STRING by the parser.
4. #### The missing semicolon; again

   If you have an unterminated expression in previous lines, then any following statement or language construct gets seen as raw identifier:

   ```
          ⇓
   func1()
   function2();
   ```

   PHP just can't know if you meant to run two functions after another, or if you meant to multiply their results, add them, compare them, or only run one `||` or the other.
5. #### Short open tags and `<?xml` headers in PHP scripts

   This is rather uncommon. But if short_open_tags are enabled, then you can't begin your PHP scripts [with an XML declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361750/why-when-add-xml-version-1-0-encoding-utf-8-to-web-page-dont-work-on-ho):

   ```
         ⇓
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   ```

   PHP will see the `<?` and reclaim it for itself. It won't understand what the stray `xml` was meant for. It'll get interpreted as constant. But the `version` will be seen as another literal/constant. And since the parser can't make sense of two subsequent literals/values without an expression operator in between, that'll be a parser failure.
6. #### Invisible Unicode characters

   A most hideous cause for syntax errors are Unicode symbols, such as the [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). PHP allows Unicode characters as identifier names. If you get a T_STRING parser complaint for wholly unsuspicious code like:

   ```
   <?php
       print 123;
   ```

   You need to break out another text editor. Or an hexeditor even. What looks like plain spaces and newlines here, may contain invisible constants. Java-based IDEs are sometimes oblivious to an UTF-8 BOM mangled within, zero-width spaces, paragraph separators, etc. Try to reedit everything, remove whitespace and add normal spaces back in.

   You can narrow it down with with adding redundant `;` statement separators at each line start:

   ```
   <?php
       ;print 123;
   ```

   The extra `;` semicolon here will convert the preceding invisible character into an undefined constant reference (expression as statement). Which in return makes PHP produce a helpful notice.
7. #### The `$` sign missing in front of variable names

   [Variables in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) are represented by a dollar sign followed by the name of the variable.

   The dollar sign (`$`) is a [sigil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_(computer_programming)) that marks the identifier as a name of a variable. Without this sigil, the identifier could be a [language keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) or a [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php).

   This is a common error when the PHP code was ["translated" from code written in another language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48365324/4265352) (C, Java, JavaScript, etc.). In such cases, a declaration of the variable type (when the original code was written in a language that uses typed variables) could also sneak out and produce this error.
8. #### Escaped Quotation marks

   If you use `\` in a string, it has a special meaning. This is called an "[Escape Character](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)" and normally tells the parser to take the next character literally.

   Example: `echo 'Jim said \'Hello\'';` will print `Jim said 'hello'`

   If you escape the closing quote of a string, the closing quote will be taken literally and not as intended, i.e. as a printable quote as part of the string and not close the string. This will show as a parse error commonly after you open the next string or at the end of the script.

   Very common error when specifiying paths in Windows: `"C:\xampp\htdocs\"` is wrong. You need `"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\"`.
9. #### Typed properties

   You need PHP ≥7.4 to use [property typing](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/typed_properties_v2) such as:

   ```
   public stdClass $obj;
   ```

Answer (score 19):

### Unexpected `(`

Opening parentheses typically follow language constructs such as `if`/`foreach`/`for`/`array`/`list` or start an arithmetic expression. They're syntactically incorrect after `"strings"`, a previous `()`, a lone `$`, and in some typical declaration contexts.

1. #### Function declaration parameters

   A rarer occurrence for this error is [trying to use expressions as default function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513714/php-unexpected-parse-error). This is not supported, even in PHP7:

   ```
   function header_fallback($value, $expires = time() + 90000) {
   ```

   Parameters in a function declaration can only be literal values or constant expressions. Unlike for function invocations, where you can freely use `whatever(1+something()*2)`, etc.
2. #### Class property defaults

   Same thing for [class member declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313051/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-expecting-or-in), where only literal/constant values are allowed, not expressions:

   ```
   class xyz {                   ⇓
       var $default = get_config("xyz_default");
   ```

   Put such things in the constructor.
   See also [Why don't PHP attributes allow functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960323/why-dont-php-attributes-allow-functions)

   Again note that PHP 7 only allows `var $xy = 1 + 2 +3;` constant expressions there.
3. #### JavaScript syntax in PHP

   Using JavaScript or [jQuery syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704064/syntax-error-unexpected-expecting-t-variable-or-in) won't work in PHP for obvious reasons:

   ```
   <?php      ⇓
       print $(document).text();
   ```

   When this happens, it usually indicates an unterminated preceding string; and literal `<script>` sections leaking into PHP code context.
4. #### isset(()), empty, key, next, current

   Both `isset()` and `empty()` are language built-ins, not functions. They [need to access a variable directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260232/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-in-d-xampp3-xampp-htdocs-contact-php). If you inadvertently add a pair of parentheses too much, then you'd create an expression however:

   ```
             ⇓
   if (isset(($_GET["id"]))) {
   ```

   The same applies to any language construct that requires implicit variable name access. These built-ins are part of the language grammar, therefore don't permit decorative extra parentheses.

   User-level functions that require a variable reference -but get an expression result passed- lead to runtime errors instead.

### Unexpected `)`

1. #### Absent function parameter

   You cannot have stray [commas last in a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278797/yii-widget-unexpected-where-is-the-error). PHP expects a value there and thusly complains about an early closing `)` parenthesis.

   ```
                 ⇓
   callfunc(1, 2, );
   ```

   A trailing comma is only allowed in `array()` or `list()` constructs.
2. #### Unfinished expressions

   If you forget something in an arithmetic expression, then the parser gives up. Because how should it possibly interpret that:

   ```
                  ⇓
   $var = 2 * (1 + );
   ```

   And if you forgot the closing `)` even, then you'd get a complaint about the unexpected semicolon instead.
3. #### Foreach as `constant`

   For [forgotten variable `$` prefixes in control statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624495/how-to-fix-syntax-error-in-php-unexpected) you will see:

   ```
                      ↓    ⇓
   foreach ($array as wrong) {
   ```

   PHP here sometimes tells you it expected a `::` instead. Because a class::$variable could have satisfied the expected $variable expression..

### Unexpected `{`

Curly braces `{` and `}` enclose code blocks. And syntax errors about them usually indicate some incorrect nesting.

1. #### Unmatched subexpressions in an `if`

   Most commonly [unbalanced `(` and `)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473504/php-syntax-error-on-line-9) are the cause if the parser complains about the opening curly `{` appearing too early. A simple example:

   ```
                                 ⇓
   if (($x == $y) && (2 == true) {
   ```

   Count your parentheses or use an IDE which helps with that. Also don't write code without any spaces. Readability counts.
2. #### { and } in expression context

   You can't use curly braces in expressions. If you confuse parentheses and curlys, it won't comply to the language grammar:

   ```
              ⇓
   $var = 5 * {7 + $x};
   ```

   There are a few exceptions for identifier construction, such as local scope variable `${references}`.
3. #### Variable variables or curly var expressions

   This is pretty rare. But you might also get `{` and `}` parser complaints for complex variable expressions:

   ```
                         ⇓
   print "Hello {$world[2{]} !";
   ```

   Though there's a higher likelihood for an unexpected `}` in such contexts.

### Unexpected `}`

When getting an "unexpected `}`" error, you've mostly closed a code block too early.

1. #### Last statement in a code block

   It can happen for any unterminated expression.

   And if the last line in a function/code block lacks a trailing `;` semicolon:

   ```
   function whatever() {
       doStuff()
   }            ⇧
   ```

   Here the parser can't tell if you perhaps still wanted to add `+ 25;` to the function result or something else.
2. #### Invalid block nesting / Forgotten `{`

   You'll sometimes see this parser error when a code block was `}` closed too early, or you forgot an opening `{` even:

   ```
   function doStuff() {
       if (true)    ⇦
           print "yes";
       }
   }   ⇧
   ```

   In above snippet the `if` didn't have an opening `{` curly brace. Thus the closing `}` one below became redundant. And therefore the next closing `}`, which was intended for the function, was not associable to the original opening `{` curly brace.

   Such errors are even harder to find without proper code indentation. Use an IDE and bracket matching.

### Unexpected `{`, expecting `(`

Language constructs which require a condition/declaration header **and** a code block will trigger this error.

1. #### Parameter lists

   For example [misdeclared functions without parameter list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471413/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-expecting-help) are not permitted:

   ```
                    ⇓
   function whatever {
   }
   ```
2. #### Control statement conditions

   And you can't likewise have an [`if` without condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749574/unexpected-expected).

   ```
     ⇓
   if {
   }
   ```

   Which doesn't make sense, obviously. The same thing for the usual suspects, `for`/`foreach`, `while`/`do`, etc.

   > If you've got this particular error, you definitely should look up some manual examples.

Comment: Was looking for answer to my question in this post, but found answer myself to the problem of - "Unexpected {", that`s why i wanted to share with my answer- for me the problem was line breaking encoding - somehow some of my files were using macintosh line breaks, but when i changed them to windows line breaks - my problem(on localhost(WAMP) everything works, but on linux webserver dont) was solved.

Comment: @EdgarsAivars Thanks for your comment! Platform-specific linebreaks are indeed an uncommon and tricky issue. I'll probably mention it within here as well. (It was just mentioned as aside in the [other reference answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18050072/345031#~type+of+linebreaks).)

Comment: I found that getting Unexpected } was because a piece of my code used the php short tag <? instead of <?php - took me a while to find this one as it worked on other servers.

Answer (score 15):

### Unexpected $end

When PHP talks about an "unexpected `$end`", it means that your code ended while the parser is expecting more code. (The message is a bit misleading when taken literally. It's not about a variable named "$end", as sometimes assumed by newcomers. It refers to the "end of file", <kbd>EOF</kbd>.)

> **Cause:** Unbalanced `{` and `}` for code blocks / and function or class declarations.

It's **pretty much always** about a missing `}` curly brace to close preceding code blocks.  What it's saying is that the parser is expecting to find a closing `}` but actually reached the end of the file.

- Again, use proper indentation to avoid such issues.
- Use an IDE with bracket matching, to find out where the `}` is amiss.
  There are keyboard shortcuts in most IDEs and text editors:

  - NetBeans, PhpStorm, Komodo: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>
  - Eclipse, Aptana: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>
  - Atom, Sublime: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> - Zend Studio <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>
  - Geany, Notepad++: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> - Joe: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> - Emacs: <kbd>C-M-n</kbd> - Vim: <kbd>%</kbd>

Most IDEs also **highlight** matching braces, brackets and parentheses.
Which makes it pretty easy to inspect their correlation:

[image: Bracket matching in an IDE]

#### Unterminated expressions

An `Unexpected $end` syntax/parser error can also occur for unterminated expressions or statements:

- `$var = func(1,` 
  `?>`<kbd>EOF</kbd>

So, look at the end of scripts first. A trailing `;` is often redundant for the last statement in any PHP script. But you *should* have one. Precisely because it narrows such syntax issues down.  Particularly after you find yourself adding more statements at the end of the script.

#### Indented HEREDOC markers

Another common occurrence appears with [HEREDOC or NOWDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) strings. The terminating marker goes ignored with leading spaces, tabs, etc.:

```
print <<< END
    Content...
    Content....
  END;
# ↑ terminator isn't exactly at the line start
```

Therefore the parser assumes the HEREDOC string to continue until the end of the file (hence "Unexpected $end"). Pretty much all IDEs and syntax-highlighting editors will make this obvious or warn about it.

#### Escaped Quotation marks

If you use `\` in a string, it has a special meaning. This is called an "[Escape Character](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)" and normally tells the parser to take the next character literally.

Example: `echo 'Jim said \'Hello\'';` will print `Jim said 'hello'`

If you escape the closing quote of a string, the closing quote will be taken literally and not as intended, i.e. as a printable quote as part of the string and not close the string. This will show as a parse error commonly after you open the next string or at the end of the script.

Very common error when specifying paths in Windows: `"C:\xampp\htdocs\"` is wrong. You need `"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\"`.  Alternately, PHP will usually convert Unix-style paths (e.g. `"C:/xampp/htdocs/"`) to the correct path for Windows.

#### Alternative syntax

Somewhat rarer you can see this syntax error when using the alternative syntax for statement/code blocks in templates. Using `if:` and `else:` and a missing `endif;` for example.

#### See also:

- *[PHP syntax error “unexpected $end”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661620/php-syntax-error-unexpected-end)*
- *[Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected end of file in my PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482527/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file-in-my-php-code)*
- *[Parse error syntax error unexpected end of file, using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473654/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file-php)*
- *[PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in a CodeIgniter View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990681/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file-in-php)*
- *[Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file (Registration script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978885/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file-registration-script)*
- *["Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end" For my uni registration assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665831/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-for-my-uni-registration-assignment)*
- [Fixing PHP Errors: PHP Error #3: Unexpected end of file](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/05/fixing-php-errors/#%7EUnexpected+end+of+file)

Answer (score 15):

### Unexpected T_IF 
Unexpected T_ELSEIF 
Unexpected T_ELSE 
Unexpected T_ENDIF

Conditional control blocks `if`, `elseif` and `else` follow a simple structure. When you encounter a syntax error, it's most likely just invalid block nesting → with missing `{` curly braces `}` - or one too many.

[image]

1. #### Missing `{` or `}` due to incorrect indentation

   Mismatched code braces are common to less well-formatted code such as:

   ```
   if((!($opt["uniQartz5.8"]!=$this->check58)) or (empty($_POST['poree']))) {if
   ($true) {echo"halp";} elseif((!$z)or%b){excSmthng(False,5.8)}elseif (False){
   ```

   If your code looks like this, start afresh! Otherwise it's unfixable to you or anyone else. There's no point in showcasing this on the internet to inquire for help.

   You will only be able to fix it, if you can visually follow the nested structure and relation of if/else conditionals and their `{` code blocks `}`. Use your IDE to see if they're all paired.

   ```
   if (true) {
        if (false) {
                 …
        }
        elseif ($whatever) {
            if ($something2) {
                …
            } 
            else {
                …
            }
        }
        else {
            …
        }
        if (false) {    //   a second `if` tree
            …
        }
        else {
            …
        }
   }
   elseif (false) {
       …
   }
   ```

   Any double `}` `}` will not just close a branch, but a previous condition structure. Therefore stick with one coding style; don't mix and match in nested if/else trees.

   Apart from consistency here, it turns out helpful to avoid lengthy conditions too. Use temporary variables or functions to avoid unreadable `if`-expressions.
2. #### `IF` cannot be used in expressions

   A surprisingly frequent newcomer mistake is trying to use an `if` statement in an expression, such as a print statement:

   ```
                      ⇓
   echo "<a href='" . if ($link == "example.org") { echo …
   ```

   Which is invalid of course.

   You can use [a ternary conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507042/if-block-inside-echo-statement), but beware of readability impacts.

   ```
   echo "<a href='" . ($link ? "http://yes" : "http://no") . "</a>";
   ```

   Otherwise break such output constructs up: use [multiple `if`s and `echo`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175753/how-to-embed-if-statement-inside-echo).
   Better yet, use [temporary variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778250/if-else-to-echo-image-in-php), and place your conditionals before:

   ```
   if ($link) { $href = "yes"; } else { $href = "no"; }
   echo "<a href='$href'>Link</a>";
   ```

   Defining functions or methods for such cases often makes sense too.

   #### Control blocks don't return "results"

   Now this is less common, but a few coders even try to treat `if` as if it could return a *result*:

   ```
   $var = if ($x == $y) { "true" };
   ```

   Which is structurally identical to using `if` within a string concatenation / expression.

   - But [control structures](http://php.net/language.control-structures) (if / foreach / while) don't have a *"result"*.
   - The literal string "true" would also just be a void statement.

   You'll have to use an assignment *in the code block*:

   ```
   if ($x == $y) { $var = "true"; }
   ```

   Alternatively, resort to a `?:` ternary comparison.

   #### If in If

   You [cannot nest an `if`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316003/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-if) within a condition either:

   ```
                       ⇓
   if ($x == true and (if $y != false)) { ... }
   ```

   Which is obviously redundant, because the `and` (or `or`) already allows chaining comparisons.
3. #### Forgotten `;` semicolons

   Once more: Each control block needs to be a statement. If the previous code piece isn't terminated by a semicolon, then that's a guaranteed syntax error:

   ```
                   ⇓
   $var = 1 + 2 + 3
   if (true) { … }
   ```

   Btw, the last line in a `{…}` code block needs a semicolon too.
4. #### Semicolon too early

   Now it's probably wrong to blame a particular coding style, as this pitfall is too easy to overlook:

   ```
               ⇓
   if ($x == 5);
   {
       $y = 7;
   }
   else           ←
   {
       $x = -1;    
   }
   ```

   Which happens more often than you might imagine.

   - When you [terminate the `if ()` expression with `;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856700/syntax-error-unexpected-t-else) it will execute a void statement. The `;` becomes a an empty `{}` of its own!
   - The `{…}` block thus is detached from the `if`, and would always run.
   - So the `else` no longer had a relation to an open `if` construct,
     which is why this would lead to an Unexpected T_ELSE syntax error.

   Which also explains a likewise subtle variation of this syntax error:

   ```
   if ($x) { x_is_true(); }; else { something_else(); };
   ```

   Where the `;` after the code block `{…}` terminates the whole `if`
   construct, severing the `else` branch syntactically.
5. #### Not using code blocks

   It's syntactically allowed to omit curly braces `{`…`}` for code blocks in `if`/`elseif`/`else` branches. Which sadly is a syntax style very common to unversed coders. (Under the false assumption this was quicker to type or read).

   However that's highly likely to trip up the syntax. Sooner or later additional statements will find their way into the if/else branches:

   ```
   if (true)
       $x = 5;
   elseif (false)
       $x = 6;
       $y = 7;     ←
   else
       $z = 0;
   ```

   But to actually use code blocks, you ***do have*** to write `{`…`}` them as such!

   > Even seasoned programmers avoid this braceless syntax, or at least
   >   understand it as an exceptional exception to the rule.
6. #### Else / Elseif in wrong order

   One thing to remind yourself is the [conditional order](http://php.net/control-structures.elseif), of course.

   ```
   if ($a) { … }
   else { … }
   elseif ($b) { … }
   ↑
   ```

   You can have as many `elseif`s as you want, but [`else` has to go last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619075/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-elseif). That's just how it is.
7. #### Class declarations

   As [mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18092318/345031), you can't have control statements in a class declaration:

   ```
   class xyz {
       if (true) {
           function ($var) {}
       }
   ```

   You either [forgot a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440036/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-if-expecting-t-function) definition, or closed one `}` too early in such cases.
8. #### Unexpected T_ELSEIF / T_ELSE

   When mixing PHP and HTML, the closing `}` for an `if/elseif` must be in the same PHP block `<?php ?>` as the next `elseif/else`.  This will generate an error as the closing `}` for the `if` needs to be part of the `elseif`:

   ```
   <?php if ($x) { ?>
       html
   <?php } ?>
   <?php elseif ($y) { ?>
       html
   <?php } ?>
   ```

   The correct form `<?php } elseif`:

   ```
   <?php if ($x) { ?>
       html
   <?php } elseif ($y) { ?>
       html
   <?php } ?>
   ```

   This is more or less a variation of incorrect indentation - presumably often based on wrong coding intentions.
       You cannot [mash other statements *inbetween*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218975/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-else-and-i-dont-know-why) `if` and `elseif`/`else` structural tokens:

   ```
   if (true) {
   }
   echo "in between";    ←
   elseif (false) {
   }
   ?> text <?php      ←
   else {
   }
   ```

   Either can only occur in `{…}` code blocks, not in between control structure tokens.

   - This wouldn't make sense anyway. It's not like that there was some "undefined" state when PHP jumps between `if` and `else` branches.
   - You'll have to make up your mind where print statements belong to / or if they need to be repeated in both branches.

   Nor can you **part an if/else** between different control structures:

   ```
   foreach ($array as $i) {
       if ($i) { … }
   }
   else { … }
   ```

   There is no [syntactic relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567002/unexpected-t-elseif) between the `if` and `else`. The `foreach` lexical scope ends at `}`, so there's no point for the `if` structure to continue.
9. #### T_ENDIF

   If an unexpected T_ENDIF is complained about, you're using the alternative syntax style `if:` ⋯ `elseif:` ⋯ `else:` ⋯ `endif;`. Which you should really think twice about.

   - A common pitfall is confusing the eerily [similar `:` colon for a `;` semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250411/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-endif-in-home-content-error-php). (Covered in "Semicolon too early")
   - As indentation is harder to track in template files, the more when using the alternative syntax - it's plausible your `endif;` does not match any `if:`.
   - Using [`} endif;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369695/syntax-error-unexpected-endif-t-endif-on-line-288)
      is a *doubled* `if`-terminator.

   While an "unexpected $end" is usually the price for a forgotten closing `}` curly brace.
10. #### Assignment vs. comparison

    So, this is not a syntax error, but worth mentioning in this context:

    ```
           ⇓
    if ($x = true) { }
    else { do_false(); }
    ```

    That's not a [`==`/`===` comparison, but an `=` assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals). This is rather subtle, and will easily lead some users to helplessly edit whole condition blocks. Watch out for unintended assignments first - whenver you experience a logic fault / misbeheviour.

Answer (score 12):

### Unexpected T_IS_EQUAL 
Unexpected T_IS_GREATER_OR_EQUAL 
Unexpected T_IS_IDENTICAL 
Unexpected T_IS_NOT_EQUAL 
Unexpected T_IS_NOT_IDENTICAL 
Unexpected T_IS_SMALLER_OR_EQUAL 
Unexpected `<` 
Unexpected `>`

Comparison operators such as `==`, `>=`, `===`, `!=`, `<>`, `!==` and `<=` or `<` and `>` mostly should be used just in expressions, such as `if` expressions. If the parser complains about them, then it often means incorrect paring or mismatched `(` `)` parens around them.

1. #### Parens grouping

   In particular for `if` statements with multiple comparisons you must take care to correctly count [opening and closing parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593505/php-unexpected-t-is-not-equal-error):

   ```
                           ⇓
   if (($foo < 7) && $bar) > 5 || $baz < 9) { ... }
                         ↑
   ```

   Here the `if` condition here was already terminated by the `)`

   Once your comparisons become sufficiently complex it often helps to split it up into multiple and nested `if` constructs rather.
2. #### isset() mashed with comparing

   A common newcomer is pitfal is trying to combine [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) or [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) with comparisons:

   ```
                           ⇓
   if (empty($_POST["var"] == 1)) {
   ```

   Or even:

   ```
                       ⇓
   if (isset($variable !== "value")) {
   ```

   This doesn't make sense to PHP, because `isset` and `empty` are language constructs that only accept variable names. It doesn't make sense to compare the result either, because the output is only/already a boolean.
3. #### Confusing `>=` greater-or-equal with `=>` array operator

   Both operators look somewhat similar, so they sometimes get mixed up:

   ```
            ⇓
   if ($var => 5) { ... }
   ```

   You only need to remember that this comparison operator is called "*greater than* or *equal*" to get it right.

   See also: [If statement structure in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551718/if-statement-structure-in-php)
4. #### Nothing to compare against

   You also can't combine two comparisons if they pertain the same variable name:

   ```
                    ⇓
   if ($xyz > 5 and < 100)
   ```

   PHP can't deduce that you meant to compare the initial variable again. Expressions are usually paired according to [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), so by the time the `<` is seen, there'd be only a boolean result left from the original variable.

   See also: [unexpected T_IS_SMALLER_OR_EQUAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148054/how-to-check-if-a-text-box-is-not-empty-and-the-value-is-less-than-500)
5. #### Comparison chains

   You can't compare against a variable with a row of operators:

   ```
                     ⇓
    $reult = (5 < $x < 10);
   ```

   This has to be broken up into two comparisons, each against `$x`.

   This is actually more a case of blacklisted expressions (due to equivalent operator associativity). It's syntactically valid in a few C-style languages, but PHP wouldn't interpret it as expected comparison chain either.
6. #### Unexpected `>` 
    Unexpected `<`

   The greater than `>` or less than `<` operators don't have a custom `T_XXX` tokenizer name. And while they can be misplaced like all they others, you more often see the parser complain about them for misquoted strings and mashed HTML:

   ```
                           ⇓
   print "<a href='z">Hello</a>";
                    ↑
   ```

   This amounts to a string `"<a href='z"` being compared `>` to a literal constant `Hello` and then another `<` comparison. Or that's at least how PHP sees it. The actual cause and syntax mistake was the premature string `"` termination.

   It's also not possible to nest PHP start tags:

   ```
   <?php echo <?php my_func(); ?>
              ↑
   ```

See also:

- [php unexpected T_IS_NOT_EQUAL error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593505/php-unexpected-t-is-not-equal-error)
- [syntax error, unexpected T_IS_EQUAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538481/syntax-error-unexpected-t-is-equal)
- [Syntax error on return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17239090/syntax-error-on-return-statement)
- http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/96891-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-is-not-identical-expecting-or/

Answer (score 11):

### Unexpected T_IF 
Unexpected T_FOREACH 
Unexpected T_FOR 
Unexpected T_WHILE 
Unexpected T_DO 
Unexpected T_ECHO

Control constructs such as `if`, `foreach`, `for`, `while`, `list`, `global`, `return`, `do`, `print`, `echo` may only be used as statements. They usually reside on a line by themselves.

1. #### Semicolon; where you at?

   Pretty universally have you [missed a semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210343/trouble-with-if-statement-php) in the previous line if the parser complains about a control statement:

   ```
                ⇓
   $x = myfunc()
   if (true) {
   ```

   Solution: look into the previous line; add semicolon.
2. #### Class declarations

   Another location where this occurs is [in class declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440036/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-if-expecting-t-function). In the class section you can only list property initializations and method sections. No code may reside there.

   ```
   class xyz {
       if (true) {}
       foreach ($var) {}
   ```

   Such syntax errors commonly materialize for incorrectly nested `{` and `}`. In particular when function code blocks got closed too early.
3. #### Statements in expression context

   Most language constructs can [only be used as statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316003/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-if). They aren't meant to be placed inside other expressions:

   ```
                      ⇓
   $var = array(1, 2, foreach($else as $_), 5, 6);
   ```

   Likewise can't you use an `if` in strings, math expressions or elsewhere:

   ```
                  ⇓
   print "Oh, " . if (true) { "you!" } . " won't work";
   // Use a ternary condition here instead, when versed enough.
   ```

   <sup>For embedding `if`-like conditions in an expression specifically, you often want to use a [`?:` ternary evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507042/if-block-inside-echo-statement).</sup>

   The same applies to `for`, `while`, `global`, `echo` and a lesser extend `list`.

   ```
             ⇓
   echo 123, echo 567, "huh?";
   ```

   Whereas `print()` is a language built-in that may be used in expression context. (But rarely makes sense.)
4. #### Reserved keywords as identifiers

   You also can't use `do` or `if` and other language constructs for user-defined functions or class names. (Perhaps in PHP 7. But even then it wouldn't be advisable.)
5. #### Your have a semi-colon instead of a colon (:) or curly bracket ({) after your control block

   Control structures are typically wrapped in curly braces (but colons can be used in an [alternative syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)) to represent their scope. If you accidentally use a semi-colon you prematurely close that block resulting in your closing statement throwing an error.

```
    foreach ($errors as $error); <-- should be : or {
```

Answer (score 10):

### Unexpected '?'

If you are trying to use `<?php` within `<?php` this error will be given*.

```
$var = 'hello '<?php echo 'world'; ?>;
```

<sup>* For PHP versions 4.3.1, 4.3.5 - 4.3.11, 4.4.0 - 4.4.1, 5.0.0 - 5.0.5, 4.4.2 - 4.4.9, 5.1.0 - 5.1.6, 5.2.0 - 5.2.17, 5.3.0 - 5.3.29, 5.4.0 - 5.4.45, 5.5.0 - 5.5.38, 5.6.0 - 5.6.40, 7.0.0 - 7.0.33, 7.1.0 - 7.1.33, 7.2.0 - 7.2.34, 7.3.0 - 7.3.31, 7.4.0 - 7.4.24</sup>

---

If you are trying to use the null coalescing operator `??` in a version of PHP prior to PHP 7 you will get this error.

```
<?= $a ?? 2; // works in PHP 7+
<?= (!empty($a)) ? $a : 2; // All versions of PHP
```

#### Unexpected '?', expecting variable

A similar error can occur for nullable types, as in:

```
function add(?int $sum): ?int {
```

Which again indicates an outdated PHP version being used (either the CLI version `php -v` or the webserver bound one `phpinfo();`).

Answer (score 6):

### Unexpected T_LNUMBER

The token `T_LNUMBER` refers to a "long" / number.

1. #### Invalid variable names

   In PHP, and most other programming languages, [variables](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) cannot start with a number. The first character must be alphabetic or an underscore.

   ```
   $1   // Bad
   $_1  // Good
   ```

   [image: *]

   - Quite often [comes up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571559/syntax-error-unexpected-t-lnumber-expecting-t-variable-or) for using `preg_replace`-placeholders `"$1"` in PHP context:

     ```
     #                         ↓            ⇓  ↓
     preg_replace("/#(\w+)/e",  strtopupper($1) )
     ```

     Where the callback should have been quoted. (Now the `/e` regex flag has been deprecated. But it's sometimes still misused in `preg_replace_callback` functions.)
   - The same identifier constraint applies to [object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606340/get-a-php-object-property-that-is-a-number), btw.

     ```
            ↓
     $json->0->value
     ```
   - While the tokenizer/parser does not allow a literal `$1` as variable name, one *could* use `${1}` or `${"1"}`. Which is a syntactic workaround for non-standard identifiers. (It's best to think of it as a local scope lookup. But generally: prefer plain arrays for such cases!)
   - Amusingly, but very much not recommended, PHPs parser allows Unicode-identifiers; such that `$➊` would be valid. (Unlike a literal `1`).
2. #### Stray array entry

   An unexpected long can also occur for [array declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22183063/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-lnumber-expecting) - when missing `,` commas:

   ```
   #            ↓ ↓
   $xy = array(1 2 3);
   ```

   Or likewise function calls and declarations, and other constructs:

   - `func(1, 2  3);`
   - `function xy($z 2);`
   - `for ($i=2 3<$z)`

   So usually there's one of `;` or `,` missing for separating lists or expressions.
3. #### Misquoted HTML

   And again, [misquoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805331/syntax-error-unexpected-t-lnumber-expecting-or) are a frequent source of stray numbers:

   ```
   #                 ↓ ↓          
   echo "<td colspan="3">something bad</td>";
   ```

   Such cases should be treated more or less like [Unexpected T_STRING](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18092277/345031) errors.
4. #### Other identifiers

   Neither functions, classes, nor [namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875380/can-a-namespace-start-with-a-number-in-php/33875381) can be named beginning with a number either:

   ```
            ↓
   function 123shop() {
   ```

   Pretty much the same as for variable names.

Answer (score 3):

### Unexpected '='

This can be caused by having invalid characters in a variable name. Variables names *must* follow these rules:

> Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'

Comment: Good addition John.

Answer (score 2):

### Unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE)

The syntax is using a colon - if there is no colon the above error will occur.

```
<?php while($query->fetch()): ?>
 ....
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The alternative to this syntax is using curly brackets:

```
<?php while($query->fetch()) { ?>
  ....
<?php } ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

Answer (score 2):

## Unexpected '.'

This can occur if you are trying to use the [splat operator(`...`)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41124015/250259) in an unsupported version of PHP.

`...` first became available in PHP 5.6 to capture a variable number of arguments to a function:

```
function concatenate($transform, ...$strings) {
    $string = '';
    foreach($strings as $piece) {
        $string .= $piece;
    }
    return($transform($string));
}

echo concatenate("strtoupper", "I'd ", "like ", 4 + 2, " apples");
// This would print:
// I'D LIKE 6 APPLES
```

In PHP 7.4, you could use it for [Array expressions](https://laravel-news.com/spread-operator-in-array-expressions-coming-to-php-7-4).

```
$parts = ['apple', 'pear'];
$fruits = ['banana', 'orange', ...$parts, 'watermelon'];
// ['banana', 'orange', 'apple', 'pear', 'watermelon'];
```

Answer (score 2):

## Unexpected `:`

#### 1. PHP 8 named parameter syntax

> unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ')'

If attempting to use PHP 8's new named parameter functionality in a version of PHP < 8 this error will occur:

```
$table->string(column:'Name');
```

**Solutions:**

1. Upgrade your version of PHP to PHP 8.0.0 or higher
2. Do not use named parameters (pass the parameters in the order they are expected)

#### 2. Cropped class `::` separator

An error message that begins Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' can be caused by mistakenly writing a class static reference `Class::$Variable` as `Class:$Variable`.

Answer (score 1):

### Unexpected 'continue' (T_CONTINUE)

`continue` is a statement (like for, or if) and must appear standalone. It cannot be used as part of an expression. Partly because continue doesn't return a value, but in an expression every sub-expression must result in some value so the overall expression results in a value. That's the difference between a statement and an expression.

That means `continue` cannot be used in a ternary statement or any statement that requires a return value.

### Unexpected 'break' (T_BREAK)

Same goes for `break;` of course. It's also not usable in expression context, but a strict statement (on the same level as `foreach` or an `if` block).

### Unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)

Now this might be more surprising for `return`, but that's also just a block-level *statement*. It does return a value (or NULL) to the higher scope/function, but it does not evaluate as expression itself. → That is: there's no point in doing `return(return(false);;`

Answer (score 1):

One more reason to occurrence of these errors is unexpected whitespace like similar characters with-in code, the code lines seems to be perfect, but they contains some specific characters which are similar to break line or whitespace or tab but they not get parsed by the parser.
I face this issue when I try to put some code from webpage to the code editor by simply copy paste, I saw this error with array definition. everything was looking right in array definition. I can't sort out right error, finally I define this array in single line, then error was gone. then again I try to make that definition multiple like but manually adding break(Enter) for each array element and saved the file this time no parsing error by editor and also no error while running it.
For Example I faced issue with this snippet which was on one blog, actually can't post those snippets ,cause stack overflow already knows the problem with code.

then after solving it my working snippet is, which looks similar with one which shows parsing error

**syntax error, unexpected ''auth'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ']'**

```
    public $aliases = [
        'csrf'=> \CodeIgniter\Filters\CSRF::class,
        'toolbar'=> \CodeIgniter\Filters\DebugToolbar::class,
        'honeypot'=> \CodeIgniter\Filters\Honeypot::class,
        'auth' => \App\Filters\Auth::class,
];
```

Comment: I feel like this is already covered by **Invisible stray Unicode characters**. It's also not that prevalent really, except for copy-and-paste coders. And if, it would be more probable to pair with unexpected T_STRING cases.

Answer (score 1):

For newbies to VS Code, if you see the syntax error, check if you have saved the file. If you have a wrong syntax, save the file, and then fix the syntax withou saving again, VS Code will keep showing you the error. The error message will disappear only after you save the file.